# How to create this effect with flutter. I used BackdropFilter but I think It's not right

Tags: flutter, blur, effect

[image: Image here]

I try to apply this effect to my UI. But I can't create a spillover effect. can I achieve this effect with container shadow

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lib builds on BackdropFilter and ImageFilter
https://pub.dev/packages/blur

This is also a useful article if you want to implement it yourself.
https://medium.com/fluttervn/how-to-make-blur-effect-in-flutter-using-backdropfilter-imagefilter-559ffd8ab73

Comment: Oh. Thank you! I use this package and it allow set value of blur.